# Is it possible to open a html page upon clicking a 'Help' button in my C++ program?

Tags: html, c++, windows

I am trying to develop a C++ program which also has a Help button on its menu bar. I'd like to know if it is possible upon clicking this button, if a html document can be opened on the browser, and if so could you explain how to please? I tried researching this but to no avail. I intend to use the html document in conjunction with CSS and JS too. Many thanks!

Comment: You need way more detail than that. Which OS ? What framework are you using to get a menu? MFC? QT? Can you post a snippet of your code that does any related parts?

Comment: Also, remove the html, css and javascript tags. What the page contains is unimportant. But add the tags for the framework and OS.

Comment: You'll need to search your operating system OS for API that launch browsers an to pass data to and from the browser.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey so I just edited my answer and Windows is the OS. As for the framework, I'm not too sure which to use. I have no code at the moment either as I'm still in the planning stage of this uni project of mine. Basically what I'm trying to do is to create an audio recorder (hence the c++ use) which has a Help and Exit button only in the menu bar.  Using the help button I want to redirect the user to an html document which is a tutorial to something else. :)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews ok thank you Thomas I'm looking into Windows documentation right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, you can do:

```
ShellExecute (NULL, __T ("open"), url, __T (""), __T ("."), SW_NORMAL);
```

where `url` is the page you want to open (e.g, `__T ("https://stackoverflow.com/")`).

This will open the page in the default browser (initially Edge, but users can change it).

Comment: Thank you Paul, is this the code I would implement into the button? I'm sorry, clearly I've some work to do..

Comment: It's the code you would execute when the button is pressed.

Comment: I see I'm starting to get a picture now. Thanks Paul \m/